# Quantum Numbers

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, orbitals

Why are the Lanthaide (atomic #'s 57-71) elements in period 6, but in terms of electron configuration, are assigned the principal quantum number of 4? Why are certain subshells assigned quantum numbers that are different than their corresponding period? (example is d-block elements as well)

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33297/why-do-3d-orbitals-have-lesser-energy-than-4s-orbitals-in-transition-metals/33310#33310 and http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/why-does-the-3rd-electron-shell-start-filling-up-with-scandium