# Why does Co(I) have a 3d8 configuration?

Tags: electronic-configuration, transition-metals

Why is the electron configuration of $\ce{Co^+}$ $[\ce{Ar}](\mathrm{3d})^8$?

Since neutral $\ce{Co}$ itself has a $[\ce{Ar}](\mathrm{4s})^2(\mathrm{3d})^7$ configuration, wouldn't the ionised electron be lost from the $\mathrm{4s}$ orbital, leading to an electron configuration of $[\ce{Ar}](\mathrm{4s})^1(\mathrm{3d})^7$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lighter elements, the shells fill in order. Starting at the transition metals, an outer s orbital *may* fill before an inner d orbital, so the electron configuration of *unioninzed* cobalt is written $\ce{[Ar]}4\mathrm s^1\,3\mathrm d^7$, rather than $\ce{[Ar]}3\mathrm d^7\,4\mathrm s^1$.

There is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A74L4E2E9bI) diagramming the electron configuration of $\ce{Co}$, $\ce{Co^{2+}}$ and $\ce{Co^{3+}}$, thought it does not *explain* the reasoning, nor does it cover the less common $\ce{Co^{+}}$ ion, produced by photoionization or as found in some [esoteric metal-organic compounds](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020169300924848), or in the [theoretical $\ce{CoCl}$](http://openmopac.net/PM7_accuracy/data_molecules/cobalt(i)%20chloride_jmol.html).

That said, the situation becomes murky for transition elements, and downright turbid for [lanthanides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanthanide) and [actinides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actinide), where f orbitals are added. For example the outermost shells of $\ce{La, Ce and Pr}$ are $\ce5\mathrm d^1\,$, then $\ce4\mathrm f^1\,5\mathrm d^1$, and then $\ce4\mathrm f3$. What happened to the Pr d electron? My understanding is that energy levels are quite close for the larger outer shells, and it is not intuitive which orbital fills first.

Comment: I have always been under the impression that for transition metals, 3d < 4s in energy. The $3d^8$ configuration of Co(I) ion is thus the norm, and it's the $4s^2 3d^{n-2)}$ configuration of neutral atoms that is the exception. Also, what exactly is the energetic drawback of having an incomplete orbital? Exchange energy only really plays a crucial role in the d5 and d10 case; it's always there for d6/d7/d8/d9, of course, but isn't large enough to affect the electron configuration.

Comment: I'm probably wrong about the 3d/4s thing, though, sorry. cf. references in https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/33310/16683. I think I should probably do some research before commenting on that.

Comment: What is it meant by 'has no incomplete orbital'. Are there not 2 half-filled orbitals in a $\ce{d^8}$ configuration?

Comment: Thanks, @M.L, my mind must have been wandering. Max numbers are, of course, s2, p6, and d10. The answer will be corrected.

Comment: So there is now way once can predict the configuration of transition metals, lanthanides, actinides ions?

Comment: So there is no way to predict the configuration for lanthanides, actinides or transition metal ions? I thought 4s was prefered to 3d and 3d9 or 3d1p prefferes to 3d9 e.g. Ni, Pd?

Comment: There *are* rules, but calculation can be **very** difficult. Consider the effort to calculate wave functions for H https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Physical_Chemistry_for_the_Biosciences_(Chang)/11%3A_Quantum_Mechanics_and_Atomic_Structure/11.10%3A_The_Schr%C3%B6dinger_Wave_Equation_for_the_Hydrogen_Atom