# Why is the 5d orbital instead of the 4f orbital filled in lanthanum?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electronic-configuration, metal

For orbitals with the same value of $n + l$ (e.g. the $\mathrm{3d}$ and $\mathrm{4p}$ orbitals), we usually expect the orbital with the lower value of $n$ to be filled earlier. Hence, for example, the $\mathrm{3d}$ orbitals are filled before the $\mathrm{4p}$ orbitals in the transition metals.

However, the electronic configuration of lanthanum is $[\ce{Xe}](\mathrm{5d})^1(\mathrm{6s})^2$, and not $[\ce{Xe}](\mathrm{4f})^1(\mathrm{6s})^2$.

I know that the $\mathrm{5d}$ and $\mathrm{4f}$ orbitals are of similar energies, but is there any better explanation for this?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/8357/27435 there is a similar question

Answer (score 9):

According to [Ground-state configurations of ionic species I through XVI for   Z = 57-74 and the interpretation of 4d-4f emission resonances in laser-produced plasmas](http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.25.275) Phys. Rev. A 25, 275 (where "I" means the neutral atom) :

> We begin therefore by showing in the left-hand
>   columns of Table I the configurations given by
>   Martin et al. for lanthanum through lutetium.
>   Here it is seen that at the fourth spectrum the 4f
>   level has in all cases fallen below 5d and 6s. This
>   is due to the well-known phenomenon of 4f wavefunction
>   collapse [reference 5]. The effective potential in
>   which the 4f electron moves is made up of an attractive
>   Coulomb term and a repulsive centrifugal
>   term, which, in general, combine to give a double
>   well potential, the height of the intervening barrier
>   depending on the nuclear charge Z. For neutral
>   atoms the field in the region of the outer potential
>   is essentially hydrogenic. The occurrence of the
>   neutral lanthanides coincides with the appearance
>   of bound 4f levels in the inner well, which, in turn,
>   is due to the deepening of the well and the lowering
>   of the potential barrier as a result of the increasing nuclear charge.

Here, "reference 5" is [Spectral Distribution of Atomic Oscillator Strengths](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.40.441) Rev. Mod. Phys. 40, 441 which goes into quantitative equations for the attractive Coulomb term and a repulsive centrifugal term.

Comment: Upon reading *Martin et al,* I immediately thought [Martin](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/4945/martin-%e3%83%9e%e3%83%bc%e3%83%81%e3%83%b3) … ^^'