# Why do the lanthanides and actinides have a 5d and 6d orbital, respectively?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electronic-configuration, rare-earth-elements

I was taught in school that the rare earth metals were the $\mathrm{f}$-orbital group. Additionally, the Aufbau principle states that the order of orbitals based on energy levels is $\mathrm{6s4f5d}$ and $\mathrm{7s5f6d}$ for the lanthanides and actinides, respectively. However, upon inspection, both periods have 15 elements whereas the $\mathrm{f}$-orbitals can only hold 14 electrons. I was able to resolve this by assigning one electron to the $\mathrm{5d/6d}$-orbital, which is correct according to [chemistry libretexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Descriptive_Chemistry/Elements_Organized_by_Block/4_f-Block_Elements/The_Lanthanides/aLanthanides%3A_Properties_and_Reactions#:%7E:text=Lanthanides%20tend%20to%20react%20with%20oxygen%20to%20form%20oxides.&text=Lanthanides%20exhibit%20strong%20electromagnetic%20and,they%20have%20strong%20magnetic%20fields.). Why does this occur for the rare earth metals?

Furthermore, according to libretexts, only some of the rare earth metals have a $\mathrm{5d/6d}$-orbital, whereas others have the $\mathrm{6s/7s}$-orbital and proceed to only fill their outermost $\mathrm{f}$-orbital. Why is this the case, and is there a way to determine which elements are like this short of simple memorization?

Comment: There are 14 elements in the lathanide/actinide series, excluding Lanthanum and Actinium. Also, the aufbau principle pretty much breaks down after period 4, don't use it for anything other than main group elements.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/47542/16683 https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74880/going-from-la-to-ce-why-is-the-extra-electron-added-into-the-4f-orbital

Comment: Yep, all of these help out a lot. Thanks!