Why is the valence layer not always the most energetic one?
The valence layer corresponds to the highest principal quantum number that appears in the electron configuration. It corresponds to electrons that contributes in chemical bound and chemical reaction.
But due to the Klechkowsky (Madelung) rule, the layer 3d is populated after the layer 4s, thus, in a sense, the layer 3d corresponds to a relative higher energy compared to the 4s.
Thus, in a scandium atom, for example, whose electron configuration is $[Ar] 4s^2 3d^1$, why do we state that there are 2 valence electrons (those of $4s^2$) instead of 1 valence electron (the one of $3d^1$), since it is easier to release the electron of $3d^1$ since it has a higher energy?

Sc definitely has (III) ox. state, so...

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/why-does-the-3rd-electron-shell-start-filling-up-with-scandium

The concept of valence electrons can be somewhat intricate, particularly in the context of transition metals such as scandium. Valence electrons are defined as the electrons present in the outermost shell that participate in chemical bonding.
For scandium, with the electron configuration
[


]
4

2
3

1
[Ar]4s
2
3d
1
, it is essential to understand how valence electrons are counted. Typically, both the
4

4s and
3

3d electrons are considered when determining the valence electrons. Although the
3

3d electron is at a higher energy level, the
4

4s electrons are more readily available for bonding due to their positioning in the outermost shell.
The reason we state that scandium has 2 valence electrons (from the
4

2
4s
2
) rather than just 1 from the
3

1
3d
1
arises from the relative accessibility of these electrons. The
4

4s electrons are involved in bonding as they are closer to the outer shell and more accessible during chemical reactions. In contrast, the
3

3d electron, while potentially contributing to bonding in certain circumstances, is often treated as less significant in simpler bonding scenarios.
In summary, although the
3

3d electron may possess higher energy in some contexts, the convention of counting valence electrons primarily includes the
4

4s electrons due to their role in chemical bonding. Thus, in the case of scandium, we recognize 2 valence electrons from the
4

2
4s
2
subshell.

The valence layer corresponds to the highest principal quantum number... - This is wrong or at least misleading.
The valence layer or rather valence electrons are those electrons where their orbital group (potentially) takes part in atom bonding, including ion formation. $\ce{Sc}$ has 3 valence electrons in both $\ce{4s}$ and $\ce{3d}$.
Additionally,  orbital energies are not fixed like shelves on the walls. Any change of electron configuration changes more or less energies of all orbitals. As consequence, energies of orbitals for elements along the period may switch the order.
This is often illustrated on the series  $\ce{K - Ca - Sc}$, where the orbital energy order is $ \text{4s < 3d < 4p}$ for $\ce{K}$, but $\text{3d < 4s < 4p}$ for $\ce{Sc}$.
Similar energy switching is for $\text{5f}$ and $\ce{6d}$ for early Actinides $\ce{Ac - Th - Pa - U}$, where $\ce{6d}$ orbitals have initially lower energy than $\text{5f}$, in contrary to Lanthanides. Therefore, first Actinides remind by oxidation numbers d-elements from periods 4-6 (see $\ce{U^{VI}}$), while Lanthanides have typically oxidation number III and only exceptionally IV.

This is entirely due to electron repulsion, and the fact that the more repulsions one has, the more energy in that state. The 3d, with its many and large orbital "shapes" is very compact relative to the s and p. So, after the addition of 1 electron, the addition of more electrons tends to add a repulsion force that is greater than the energy it would take to push an electron into the 4s orbital.
Because the 3d orbitals tend to have higher energies due to repulsions, it is much easier to generalize the whole sublevel as being a slightly higher energy than the 4s orbital. This is because, functionally, the 4s electrons will be at lower energy, and so it is easier to teach just to fill them first, rather than thinking of filling the first d orbital, then filling in the s orbital with two electrons.
