Why does every type of hybridisation include 's'-orbital?
I am a high-school student learning about hybridisation. From sp to sp3d2/d2sp3 (for coordination compounds), each type of hybridisation includes 's'-orbital. My teacher says it's because the 's'-orbital provides for the orientation or spatial arrangement of the hybridised orbitals at angles for minimum repulsion.
I searched it up and saw a similar question:
what's the importance of "s" character in hybrid orbitals?
I don't really understand this and would appreciate if someone could explain in a simpler way, without all the mathematical stuff.

s orbitals have less energy than p orbitals or d orbitals, so they're filled first. If you started by filling in the p orbitals, you'd be wasting energy you didn't have to waste, since it would be easier to put electrons in s orbitals.

@unstable thank you for your answer, but I wanted to understand how the 's'-orbital helps in the arrangement of the hybridised orbitals. there are answers in the link I have attached in the question, but there are some mathematical things which I don't understand, so I was hoping for someone to explain me the same stuff without the maths

I think the simplest answer is that s orbitals tend to be close in energy to either p or d orbitals, but not both at the same time. If orbitals have similar energy then they mix and you get hybrid orbitals. This also means you better forget some "sp3d2/d2sp3" - p and d hardly ever mix to any serious extent.

@Mithoron I am not really aware of modern theories, and only stating what I've learnt from my school textbooks, according to which 3d, 4s and 4p subshells do have similar energy levels enough to combine their orbitals and form d2sp3 hybridisation and same goes for 4s, 4p and 4d subshells for sp3d2. So according to that, 's'-orbital does have energy level close to orbitals of 'p' and 'd'...

Well, the point is, they really don't. You can even see it on plots like this one https://i.sstatic.net/ebLSy.png So, maybe get a newer textbook.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/why-does-the-3rd-electron-shell-start-filling-up-with-scandium

The real p orbitals have two lobes with different sign. One lobe has the same sign as the s orbital and this lobe adds constructively to the s orbital, while the lobe with opposite sign adds destructively. The constructive part gets "enhanced" which leads to the large pointy part of the sp hybrid orbital while the destructive side gets smaller. In this sense the s orbital (or rather the relative phase between the s orbital and the p orbital lobes) decides in which direction the hybrid orbital points, i.e. the direction in which the s and p orbital have the same sign.
However, the s orbital has no effect on the angles between the different hybrid orbitals. This is determined by mixing the  $p_x,p_y,p_z$ with different contributions in the hybrid orbitals.
Take a $sp^2$ hybridized carbon atom as example. The functional form of the hybrid orbitals is given by
$$\begin{aligned}
\psi_1 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}( s + \sqrt{2}p_x) \\
\psi_2 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}s - \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}p_x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}p_y\\
\psi_3 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}s - \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}p_x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}p_y 
\end{aligned}$$
The first hybrid orbital $\psi_1$ points along the x-axis. The second hybrid orbital points in a upper-left direction in the xy-plane, and the last hybrid orbital points into the lower-left direction in the xy-plane.

If you had left out the s-orbital, the white and blue regions whould have exactly the same size. By including the s orbital you clearly improve the positive overlap with trigonally arranged ligands, for example 3 hydrogen atoms, which improves the bonding.

First off, the "s" orbital is spherical in shape, meaning it doesn’t point in any particular direction. This property is really important because it helps create a more balanced structure when mixed with other orbitals like "p" or "d." By including the "s" orbital, the hybrid orbitals can form stable arrangements that minimize the repulsion between the electrons involved in bonding.
For example, in sp3 hybridization, the orbitals arrange themselves to create a tetrahedral shape with bond angles of about 109.5°. The presence of the "s" orbital helps achieve this specific angle and arrangement.
The energy level of the hybrid orbitals also plays a role. When the "s" orbital mixes with "p" or "d" orbitals, it helps bring the energy of the resulting hybrid orbitals to a more average level. This leads to bonds that are more consistent in strength and length, making the overall structure of the molecule more stable.
TLDR: the inclusion of the "s" orbital in hybridization is crucial because it ensures that the hybrid orbitals are well-balanced, allowing for optimal angles and reducing electron repulsion, which ultimately leads to more stable and symmetrical molecular shapes.

thank you for your answer; the point about energy level clears up things, but you did not explain how including the 's'-orbital helps to create a more stable arrangement. Someone here had answered before, but they deleted their answer for some reason. They explained it better, through constructive and destructive interference of orbitals. If only they could post their answer again, it would clarify everything.
